# Import and Execute a Plugin from Another Plugin in Nuxt

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a base plugin that does some Vue prototyping like so:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import mitt from "mitt"

Vue.prototype.emitter = mitt()
...
```

I have another plugin that needs to prefetch some data from a Laravel API and return it to this plugin so the results can be prototyped.

How can I access that other plugin from here to execute it?

Or how can I access `app` from Nuxt in this plugin without it being destructured in a function signature?

I'm happy to make the API call here in this plugin, but I don't see how to do that without access to `app` or `$axios`

Comment: maybe you can pass the `$axios` as a param to `emitter` like `Vue.prototype.$emitter = mitt(axios){}; `, call it in vue instance: `this.$emitter(this.$axios);`

Comment: `$axios` isn't available to pass in. It seems weird that I can't access anything inside here, it's a registered plugin.